# Windows phone 8.1 button click arguments

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to pass arguments on button click in Windows Phone 8.1?

I have a grid of 5x5 buttons, and they should all call the same method but with a different parameter. I am adding a handler like this:

```
foreach (var child in buttonGrid.Children)
{
    Button b = child as Button;
    if (b != null)
    {
        b.Click += Button_Click;
        // I want to add an argument to this
    }
}
```

Now the only way I can get the index of the button is by iterating over the whole grid and checking if the sender is equal to the button:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonGrid.Children.Count; i++)
    {
        if (sender == buttonGrid.Children[i])
        {
            DoSomething(i);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but I don't really like this approach. Is there a more efficient way of doing this (other than creating a different method for each of the 25 buttons)?

I tried searching on the internet, but the documentation and examples for Windows Phone are really lacking. If anyone has a good repository of Windows Phone 8.1 tutorials to direct me to, that would also be of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Tag` property of the button.

**For eg.**

I'm trying to create a number pad which has 9 buttons with the respective number as the button content and i have set the same thing as the `Tag` property also.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Button Content="1" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Click="Button_Click" Tag="1" />
        <Button Content="2" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Click="Button_Click" Tag="2" />
        <Button Content="3" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Click="Button_Click" Tag="3" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="4" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Click="Button_Click" Tag="4" />
        <Button Content="5" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Click="Button_Click" Tag="5" />
        <Button Content="6" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Click="Button_Click" Tag="6" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="7" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Click="Button_Click" Tag="7" />
        <Button Content="8" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Click="Button_Click" Tag="8" />
        <Button Content="9" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Click="Button_Click" Tag="9" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

This produces the following output :

[image: Output]

In your code behind you can now use the `Tag` property in the following manner

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tag = (sender as Button).Tag;

    int t = Convert.ToInt16(tag);

    switch (t)
    {
        case 1:

            //Do Something
            break;

        case 2:

            //Do Something
            break;

        case 3:

            //Do Something
            break;

        case 4:

            //Do Something
            break;

        case 5:

            //Do Something
            break;

        case 6:

            //Do Something
            break;

        case 7:

            //Do Something
            break;

        case 8:

            //Do Something
            break;

        case 9:

            //Do Something
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks.

And you can also assign Tags programatically when I initialize the Page, so I don't even have to write <Button Tag="1" /> for every button individually.

Comment: Yeah u r right...  that didn't strike me at that time...  Nice suggestion... :)

Answer (score 2):

Controls and other elements in XAML have a `Tag` property that you can set to an arbitrary object value for this kind of thing. Set it when you create the object and then inspect it in the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to assign unique numbers to each button and then call the function with this uniquely assigned number as a parameter.

In the function, you could easily use the If-Else blocks to perform the task according to the Unique Number.

The code for 4 buttons becomes something like:-

```
void func(int unique_number)
{
    if(unique_number==1)
    {
        //perform tasks for button 1
    }

    if(unique_number==2)
    {
        //perform tasks for button 2
    }

    if(unique_number==3)
    {
        //perform tasks for button 3
    }

    if(unique_number==4)
    {
        //perform tasks for button 4
    }

}

private void Button_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   func(1); //Call from button 1
}

private void Button_2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   func(2); //Call from button 2
}

private void Button_3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   func(3); //Call from button 3
}

private void Button_4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   func(4); //Call from button 4
}
```

I hope this makes it somewhat easy and efficient.

Comment: I said I didn't want to make a handler function for every single button, as that wold be too unreadable for a big grid.
The Tag property is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

While the answers show you how to do this using `Tag`, this approach is non-convenient for, say 100 buttons.

To achieve your result, you can use closures for the job. Here's how:

```
// When you're attaching handlers
int i=0;
foreach (var child in buttonGrid.Children)
{
    Button b = child as Button;
    if (b != null)
    {
        b.Click += () => {
            int z = i++; // You can put a different id generator here as well, like int z = <rand>%<prime> if you want
            DoSomething(z); // DoSomething called with corrosponding button id
        }
    }
}
```

This approach does not require you to use tags!